# Async/await in .Net --> Calling a service method that has no async implementation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

Basically I need to make a remote request using a vendor's .Net SDK for some information.  Their SDK has no async implementations on their methods so I am trying to come up with something on my own.  I bascially want to fire off this request to a synchronous method, and wait on it for only a certain amount of time.  If the request takes too long, I need to act and report that down to the client in our web app.

I'm wondering if this is the best way to do this, or is there a better way?  The code below is a service method that is called from a Controller action.

```
    public async Task<bool> SignersAdded(string packageId)
    {
        var timeout = 5000;

        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var package = _eslClient.GetPackage(new PackageId(packageId));
            return package != null && package.Documents.Values.Any(x => x.Signatures.Any());
        });

        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        while (!task.IsCompleted)
        {
            if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= timeout)
                return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Why not pass a `CancellationToken` with a timeout instead of all the stopwatch stuff? The `while` turns your async code into blocking calls anyway. You also need to use `await` for this to be correct...

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do here but it sounds like you have misunderstood the usage of async/await.

Comment: What kind of client does this SDK make? You should be able to specify the  timeout. For example with soap you can specify a timeout https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.services3.messaging.soapclient.timeout.aspx

Comment: Does their SDK offer any other form of asynchronous APIs, like BeginXXX/EndXXX APM pattern or event-based AEP pattern APIs?

Answer (score 0):

`Task.Wait` has an overload that takes an `int` which defines timeout.

```
public Task<bool> SignersAdded(string packageId)
{
    var timeout = 5000;

    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var package = _eslClient.GetPackage(new PackageId(packageId));
        return package != null && package.Documents.Values.Any(x => x.Signatures.Any());
    });

    if(!task.Wait(1000 /*timeout*/))
    {
        // timeout
        return false;
    }
    return task.Result;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it may exhaust the ASP.NET thread pool very quickly, by leaving those `GetPackage` calls hanging on pool thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your method doesn't `await` on anything, so it runs synchronously. Also, your `while` loop will spin the CPU, blocking the calling code until the task is complete.

A better approach might be this:

```
var task = Task.Run(/* your lambda */)
var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(timeout), task);
return finishedTask == task;
```

This way we create a separate delay task for that time and we await until the first task is complete. This will run in a truly asynchronous manner - there is no `while` loop that will burn CPU cycles.

(The above assumes timeout is in milliseconds. If not, then use an overload to `Delay` taking a `TimeSpan` argument instead.)

Comment: Should also be noted that `Task.WhenAny` doesn't cancel the task, it just returns when the first one completes.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct: start a task that calls GetPackage. After that you can continue doing other things.

After a while when you need the result you can wait for the task to complete. However you don't have to do Task.Wait. It is much easier to use async / await.

To do this, you have to do three things:

- Declare your function **async**
- Instead of void return Task and instead of type TResult return Task`<TResult`>. You already did that.
- Instead of waiting for the task to finish use **await**

Your function would look much simpler:

```
public **async** Task<bool> SignersAdded(string packageId)
{
   var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
   var task = Task.Run(() =>
   {
      var package = _eslClient.GetPackage(new PackageId(packageId));
      return package != null
          && package.Documents.Values
                    .Any(x => x.Signatures.Any());
    });

    // if desired you can do other things here
    // once you need the answer start waiting for it and return the result:
    return await Task;
}
```

> if you have a function that returns TResult the async version of it returns Task`<TResult`>.
>
> the return value of await Task`<TResult`> is TResult

However, if you want to be able to wait with a timeout you can do the following:

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
// cancel after 1 second
try
{
    return await task.Run( () => ..., tokenSource.Token);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException exc)
{
    // handle timeout
}
finally
{
    // do necessary cleanup
}
```

The disadvantage of making your function async is that all callers also have to be async and all have to return Task or Task`<TResult`>. There is one exception:

> An event handler can be async but may return void

Example:

```
private async void OnButton1_clicked(object sender,   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the TaskCompletionSource and the CancellationToken class. Samples here: [Timeout an async method implemented with TaskCompletionSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760252/timeout-an-async-method-implemented-with-taskcompletionsource) or [How to cancel a TaskCompletionSource using a timout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263082/how-to-cancel-a-taskcompletionsource-using-a-timout)