# How to abort a function that takes more than 3 seconds to execute?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a recursive function called `bool IsMagicNumber(int n)` that returns if `n` is a magic number or not.

If the function takes more than 3 seconds to verify if `n` is a magic number, it means `n` is not a magic number and I want to abort the function immediatly and start testing the next number.

My situation is something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    Console.WriteLine(IsMagicNumber(i));
}
```

Preprocessing results is not an option since `IsMagicNumber` can return different values for the same input.

How can I modify my code to abort the execution of `IsMagicNumber(i)` for an `i` that is taking too long (and just print `false` and move to `i + 1`)?

Comment: "Abort" as forceful termination from outside (impossible to do correctly) or as "cancel cooperatively" (i.e. using CancellationToken)?

Comment: Can you run `IsMagicNumber` in a background `Task` ? Then you can simply cancel the Task after 3 seconds.

Comment: i would pass the time limit to the function and have it check every now and then

Comment: @PoulBak there is no such thing as "simply cancel task" - task **must** cooperate and check cancellation token once in  a while anyway... So really no gain in running as separate task.

Comment: Is using Task the best option I've got? I'm not so familiar so I will give it a look.

Comment: I think if you are looking for cooperative cancellation (not aborting the code forcefully) than @pm100 suggestion (implemented either directly with TimeSpan or I'd use CancellationToken like shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263082/how-to-cancel-a-taskcompletionsource-using-a-timeout since it already wraps time checking code) is the one you should go with. There is no benefit I can see from using Task or starting code on separate thread.

Comment: [Here you go](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/cancel-async-tasks-after-a-period-of-time#complete-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you really have three options.

Use a **timeout parameter**, combined with the repeated timeout check inside your function (here I'm using a `Stopwatch` to achieve this):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(IsMagicNumber(i, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)));
}

bool IsMagicNumber(int i, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    // Somewhere in your algorithm, presumably inside a loop:
    if (stopwatch.Elapsed >= timeout)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use a **cancellation token**, which will throw an `OperationCanceledException` after 3 seconds (here I'm using a `CancellationTokenSource` with the `delay` parameter of `3000` milliseconds):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    try
    {
        using var timeoutTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(3000);
        Console.WriteLine(IsMagicNumber(i, timeoutTokenSource.Token));
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        // Continue.
    }
}

bool IsMagicNumber(int i, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Somewhere in your algorithm, presumably inside a loop:
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

**Not recommended**: Run your function in a separate thread, then use `Thread.Abort` to kill it, if you really have no other options. This will only work on the "classic" .NET Framework:

```
var thread = new Thread(p => IsMagicNumber((int)p));

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    thread.Start(i);

    if (!thread.Join(3000))
    {
        thread.Abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would upvote if you removed the `Abort` section. Even though you've said "Not recommended" it is still encouraging the use of `Abort`.

Comment: @Enigmativity It would be unfair to not mention it. And I don't get how "not recommended" in bold could be in any way encouraging.

Answer (score -2):

## Using Thread Library

I found a sample for creating thread and writed this code, hope this helps

```
ExampleThread exampleThread = new ExampleThread();

Thread myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(exampleThread.thread));

myThread.Start();

Thread.Sleep(1000); // 1 second

if (myThread.IsAlive)
    myThread.Abort();

class ExampleThread
{
    public void thread()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello : {i}");
        }
    }
}
```

For this loop when 1 second ended thread aborted and last loop output is:

```
Hello : 79490
```

So you can abort thread if it is running too long (you can decide how long with milliseconds, 1000 milliseconds = 1 second)

Comment: Never ever ever abort a thread. It's dangerous and can corrupt the run-time so you cannot rely on the running code even in the remaining threads.